# How we can convert contentVersion Title to string ,i am getting some type casting error

Tags: apex, string, contentversion

[image]

Please help me where i am writing wrong.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out how to get the best from the community. Title is a String field already, why are you looking to convert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SFSE, and as explained by @TSmith, please follow the guidelines of SFSE in all of the questions.

There are multiple best practices missed in the code but to solve the problem refer below.
As docName is a List of ContentVersion, docName[0] will provide a single element of ContentVersion (which is not required to be converted into the string), instead you need ContentDocument.Title, so the code would be

```
String name = docName[i].ContentDocument.Title;
```

I hope, doDeleteExistingDoc is not doing any DML else move it outside the for loop. As I said, there are other multiple best practices missed which need to be corrected.

Note: I have not run this code, and have just used the code mentioned in your screenshot.